# How to get session in java bean?

Tags: java, jsp, session, javabeans

I'm working on a JSP Project. 
I have a JSP file that uses a java bean. I would get session in java bean (.java).

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

With the following code in servlets:

```
request.getSession();
```

or in the jsp you have it directly with:

```
session
```

or in the bean (if you don't use it as servlet), you have to give it directly, e.g. `setSession(HttpSession session){}`. There is no way, the bean could know of the session, if you don't give it to the bean! But I don't really see a use of giving the session to the bean (probably you want to use servlets, not beans).

Comment: @ Satya With the first one. Java class called by jsp is called servlet. You get the request Object with the calling method (doGet or doPost). I added the case for bean without servlet (forgot he said bean).

Comment: I use bean for multi-language. Bean contains all strings in several languages . I store current language in user session. So, Java Bean get current language from user session and returns strings in selected language to JSP file . JSP file uses these strings to set text and components. Is it wrong?

Comment: You can just use a method like: `String getString(String currentLanguage)` and call it with `getString((String) session.getAttribute("language")))` hence your bean wont need the session but just the parameter. Or just save the language in a field in the bean. One of these would be better (if you change often the language, the first one would be better, if you change the language seldom, the last one might be the better solution). But probably for your use-case a servlet would serve this purpose better (unless the strings are session-related)